# fancybox not showing on click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox

Here's how the fancybox's script referenced:

[Master page]

```
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head id="Head1" runat="server">
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/Jquery/jquery.js"></script>
                    <!-- Add jQuery library -->

                    <!-- Add fancyBox -->
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Script/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Script/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Script/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="975px" align="center">
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderMiddle" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

And here's the aspx page (using the master page)

```
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMiddle" runat="Server">
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox(
                {
                    'width': 1300,
                    'height': 1300,
                    'showCloseButton': true
                });
        });
    </script>
   <a class="fancybox" rel="fancybox-button" href="/Information/EmployeeInfo.aspx" >
        <img src="http://snag.gy/vRRIB.jpg" />test image</a>
</asp:Content>
```

The problem is: whenever the anchor is clicked, instead of poping up a fancybox, the page's url changed (i.e. it's like no fancybox is being loaded). How to fix this problem?

Comment: just cut fancybox document.ready and paste it in master page

Comment: What do you want to display in pop-up , this form <form id="form1" runat="server"> or what?

Comment: @Karan Adhikari I would like to display yahoo in a popup

Comment: @KaranAdhikari Like the popup in this page: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla I copied the code to the master page but the result is still the same...

Comment: this is fine but what do you want to display inside popup?? I mean this Image http://snag.gy/vRRIB.jpg or form?

Comment: @KaranAdhikari  I would like to display an aspx page inside the popup. An image snag.gy/vRRIB.jpg will be shown on the page and when the user clicks the image, a popup containing the aspx page [EmployeeInfo.aspx] will be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I figured out:

Old code:

```
 <a class="fancybox" rel="fancybox-button" href="/Information/EmployeeInfo.aspx" >
        <img src="http://snag.gy/vRRIB.jpg" />test image</a>
```

New code:

```
 <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" rel="fancybox-button" href="/Information/EmployeeInfo.aspx" >
        <img src="http://snag.gy/vRRIB.jpg" />test image</a>
```

I added fancybox.iframe and it worked..